# Why isn't there a minimum required length for text in answers?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, code-only-answers

With every answer I try my best to be as detailed and thorough as possible, providing as much information as I can, so it really bothers when I see answers that don't explain what the code does or provide relevant links that do, **I.E:** code only answers.

All Stack Overflow posts have a minimum required length (10-15 characters, I think?) but when you put code in your answer, the characters of that block of code are counted as text.

What I'm saying is that the following (example) *"answer"* meets the mandatory minimum size:

```
interface Greet {
  hello(name: string): void;
  goodbye(name: string): void;
}

const HELLO_PREFIX: string = "Hello";
const GOODBYE_PREFIX: string = "Goodbye";

export const Greet: Greet = {
  hello(name: string): void {
    console.log(`${HELLO_PREFIX} ${name}!`);
  },

  goodbye(name: string): void {
    console.log(`${GOODBYE_PREFIX} ${name}!`);
  },
}

Greet.hello("Stack");
Greet.goodbye("Overflow");
```

Despite containing no text or comments and failing to explain what the provided code does or where each section of the code is supposed to go.

Why is this allowed and why isn't there a mandatory minimum **TEXT** limit for answers?

**NOTE:** I use the term *"posts"* but I'm only talking about answers.

Comment: There are still a few special cases such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/1555788.

Comment: (note. In the case above it seems that there are too many people upvote the answer because they like it, because it's unusual. We definitely don't want to encourage answers with no explanation...)

Comment: What if the explenation exists in the form of in-code comments?

Comment: Maybe the answerer does not wish its code copied directly into a 'provide full explanation' homework answer memo component....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because sometimes a short answer is still the right answer.

Code only answers can be immensely helpful. It's best if they are explained and fleshed out, but there are a ton of answers out there that do their work perfectly fine without additional prose.

If you feel an answer is not useful enough:

- **Use your votes.**
- And/or comment on the answer and request the poster works a bit on their post.
- Or even suggest an edit explaining what the code does, if you understand what it does.

No need for artificial filters. These tend to do more harm than good, and are too easily circumvented with Lorem Ipsum filler.

Comment: The last option (to edit) would be hard if you don't have the privilege, because it would be hard to expect the reviewer to check if the explanation is correct.

Comment: That would be up to the reviewer, depend on the kind of explanation offered, and on the edit message provided. But in general, I would consider it a fine use of a suggested edit: improves an existing post without altering the poster intention.